# Delete specific element from array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to delete an element from an array property on a node using Cypher.

I know the value of the element I want to delete, but not its index.

e.g. suppose I have a node like

```
({some_array: ["apples", "oranges"]})
```

I want a query like (pseudocode):

```
MATCH (n)
REMOVE "oranges" IN n.some_array
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cypher doesn't have functions for *mutating* arrays, but you can create a new array with `"oranges"` removed using [`FILTER`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#functions-filter):

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE HAS(n.some_array)
SET n.array = FILTER(x IN n.some_array WHERE x <> "oranges");
```

Answer (score 13):

The **FILTER** and **HAS** function are both deprecated:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-filter

They consider using [variable IN list WHERE predicate] instead. You just have to erase the filter() by brackets:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS(n.some_array)
SET n.array = [x IN n.some_array WHERE x <> "oranges"];
```

Worked in my case perfectly

**Update:**

Thanks ANONYMUS for pointing out that "HAS()" is replaced with "EXISTS()"

Comment: "The has() function has been superseded by exists() and has been removed." So the above statement will be like
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS(n.some_array)
SET n.array = [x IN n.some_array WHERE x <> "oranges"];

Comment: Thanks for the information i will update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we can get an error in above Query as "Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 2"
to remove this we can also use as

```
match (t:test) 
with t,FILTER(x IN t.some_array WHERE x <> "ORANGES") as filterdList
set t.array=filterdList
return t
```

Comment: Yes Vipul, but can you please tell me why this error occurs.